# Zend_Form SubForm input name differs

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I followed the tutorial here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.advanced.html on creating a multi-page form in Zend Framework. However, I'm displaying the form slightly differently and it's led to unexpected behavior. If I display the form like this:

```
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

I end up with the expected input with **name="user[username]"**:

```
<dt id="user-username-label">
  <label for="user-username" class="required">Username:</label></dt>
<dd id="user-username-element">
  <input type="text" name="user[username]" id="user-username" value="" /></dd>
```

However, if I want a little more control over how the individual form elements are displayed:

```
<?php echo $this->form->username; ?>
```

I get **name="username"**:

```
<dt id="username-label">
  <label for="username" class="required">Username:</label></dt>
<dd id="username-element">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" /></dd>
```

What's interesting is that the submit button gets the correct **name="user[submit]"** either way. What gives? Is there something `Zend_Form::__toString()` or `Zend_Form::render()` that I'm missing?